# Access files that were created by my application

Tags: android, file, kotlin, mediastore

I am using `MediaStore` to create files on Android, then I need to access them for reading. How can I do this?

Is there a way to query all my files, or filter them by application owner through `ContentResolver` somehow, or maybe I can mark my files at the creation time to filter them by this mark later?

---

My code:

```kotlin
val resolver: ContentResolver = /* Is passed as an argument */
val collection = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
} else MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI

fun createFile(): Uri? {
    val fileDetails = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "example.aac")
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
            put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_PENDING, 1)
    }

    return resolver.insert(collection, fileDetails)
}

/* Between calling these two functions I also set `IS_PENDING` to 0 */

fun findRecordings(): List<MyFile> {
    val projection = arrayOf(
        MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
        /* ... */
    )
    val selection = /* Filter to only get the files created by my app */
    val selectionArgs = /* ... */
    val sortOrder = /* ... */

    val files = mutableListOf<MyFile>()

    resolver.query(collection, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder)?.use { cursor ->
        val idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID)
        /* Other columns */

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            val id = cursor.getLong(idColumn)
            /* Other data */

            val uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(collection, id)

            files += MyFile(uri, /* ... */)
        }
    }

    return files
}
```

Comment: Put them in a folder you create first.

Comment: @blackapps But if I use `MediaStore` to create a file, I don't get to choose the folder it will be created in. I can only specify the collection (`MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`, for example)

Comment: No. You can specify your own subfolder in an existing public folder too.

Comment: @blackapps Can you please explain, how to do this? I obtain a `Uri` to save to as shown in my previous comment. I know, I can append id to it, but how can I set a subfolder?

Comment: Please post complete code. And you are asking something pretty basic. It looks as if you did not read any page tagged `mediastore`.

Comment: @blackapps I read dev.android and googled a lot, but didn't find anything that might help me on latest Android versions. Added my current code in the question.

Comment: You use already column .DISPLAY_NAME to set the file name. There is another column to set destination folder. And indeed you did not read one stackoverflow page tagged `mediastore` as within reading three posts you would have known how to do it.

Comment: @blackapps Thanks, finally managed to do it with `RELATIVE_PATH` and `DATA` columns (depends on Android version)! I'll accept your answer, if you write one, or I'll write my own otherwise.

Comment: @eyafi, blackapps spends a lot of time replyng to posts but hardly ever offers code or helpful suggestions. Most of his posts appear to give you the feeling that you are being an idiot for not knowing the answer in the first plave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to create a subfolder and save my files there. For that I used `MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH` on `>= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q` and `MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA` on other version of Android.